# Find whether embedded document exists in array and get the parent document's a property value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate-functions

I want to find  whether embedded document exists in array property of parent document and get the parent document's a property value.
Think, I have a document like this

```
{
_id:1,
persons:[{name: "Jack", earning: 1000},{name: "Monica", earning: 2000}]
totalDebt:500

}
```

I want to find whether `name=Jamal` exists in person array's embedded document and with this the `totalDebt` of `_id=1`

The result will be like this:

```
{
 totalDebt:500,
 exists:false   // as Jamal does not exists
}
```

How execute this in a single query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can easily solve this by using one query. I solved this by one query using `$cond`, Look below code to get a brief understanding.

```
db.getCollection('collectionName').aggregate([
{
 $project: {
   _id: 0,
   totalDebt: 1,
   "exists": {
      $cond: {
       if: {
         $in: [
           "Jack",
           "$persons.name"
         ]
       },
         then: true,
         else: false
      }
    }
  }
 }
])
```

Comment: It is not working for me, I tested it before posting this question.

Comment: Sure, it will work, Just now I tested in my machine, it worked perfectly. Let me know, what is the issue, you facing in this method

Comment: In my case "exists" returns always false in spite of having persons.name = "Jack", but the answer will be` true`

Comment: Can you share your complete code on this? So let me find, what was the issue there

Comment: I found the solution. Instead of using $eq, use $in operator to achieve.$project : 
         { 
            _id:0,
            totalDebt : 1 , 
           "exists" :  { $in: ["Jack", "$persons.name"] }
          }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215946/discussion-between-mhj-and-mei).

Answer (score 0):

Initially, I have used $cond with $eq operator, it always returns false. When I use $in, it solved my problem.

[image]